# Foreach with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form, e.g:

**HTML:**

```
Your favorite food?
 Pizza: <input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="0" />
 Beef: <input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="1" />
 Eggs: <input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="2" />

Your Email?
  <input type="text" name="email" />
```

I could get the result via foreach():

```
foreach($_POST['food'] as $food) { 
  echo $food;
}
```

Where I should put the Insertion query when the user choose more than one food:

```
$query = $DB->insert("INSERT INTO table VALUES('NULL','$food','$email')");
```

**BS:**

I should insert one row even if the user choose 3 foods. The food field accept more than one value

example:

**user 1:**

```
email: david@gmail.com
food: 1
```

**user 2:**

```
email: jack@gmail.com
food: 0 1 2
```

Comment: Um, within the loop? Not sure what your question is. Be careful to avoid [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) by the way

Comment: Please consider using mysql_real_escape_string or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: I don't understand that.

Comment: @Pekka + @Mark Byers : yes this is not the real code, it's an example :) I'm already using: using mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Well then try to batch the inserts like delphist suggested, to avoid one request per loop iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put this query in foreach if you want to save each record in new row.

```
$query = array();
foreach($_POST['food'] as $food) { 
  $query[] = "('NULL','$food','$email')";
}
$query = $DB->insert("INSERT INTO table VALUES ".implode(',', $query).");
```

or if you want to store all foods in single row then you can use as

```
$foods = implode(',', $_POST['food']);
$query = $DB->insert("INSERT INTO table VALUES('NULL','$foods','$email')");
```

This will save `foods` in format of `food1,food2,food3`

Comment: it would make 3 queries for `food1,food2,food3`

Comment: `INSERT INTO table VALUES('NULL','food1','email@example.com')`, `INSERT INTO table VALUES('NULL','food2','email@example.com')`, `INSERT INTO table VALUES('NULL','food3','email@example.com')`

Comment: I have this code in the begin `foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($value));
} ` and it avoid the new code: `$foods = implode(',', $_POST['job']);`

Comment: string_tags works with string not array. And in foreach you were is using it with array. was it working. You can use mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(implode(',', $_POST['job'])));

Comment: I have a lot of fields :) so I have a foreach in the begin with mysql_real_escape_string for the all fields as I mentioned in the comment above

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_body = array();
foreach($_POST['food'] as $v) { 
  $query_body[] = '(\'NULL\', \''.addslashes($v).'\', \''.addslashes($email).'\')';
}

if(count($query_body)) {
  $query = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES '.implode(',', $query_body);
}
```

Comment: should be implode(',', $query_body) not implode($query_body, ', ')

Comment: with this code i get more than one row :) I should get insert one row with one email